# How to remove a unique key in an update hook

Tags: database

I have a primary key and a unique key in my modules' schema.  I need to remove the unique key.

To remove an an index it is simple:

```
function draggableviews_update_7205() {
  if (db_index_exists('draggableviews_structure', 'entity_id')) {
    db_drop_index('draggableviews_structure', 'entity_id', array('entity_id'));
  }
}
```

There is a db_index_exists() function.  There is db_drop_unique_key() and db_add_unique_key() function, but no db_unique_key_exist().

How do I remove the unique key in an update hook?

Comment: Also drupal_get_schema() does not work, because the unique key is getting removed from schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the core schema classes (mysql, pgsql & sqlite) check for the existence of the constraint before actually dropping, so you don't have to check yourself. If you do you're actually doubling up on a DB op unnecessarily.

To cover all eventualities your code could look something like this:

```
try {
  if (db_drop_unique_key($table, $name)) {
    // Constraint was found and removed.
  }
  else {
    // Constraint was not found, nothing was altered.
  }
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  // Constraint was found, but something went wrong, see $e->getMessage() for more info.
  throw new DrupalUpdateException($e->getMessage);
}
```

Incidentally, a unique constraint is treated the same as an index by the core schema classes, so `db_index_exists()` can be used to check for them too.

Comment: I did not know that about db_index_exists(), however in that case, will it not allows return true, with the primary key the same.

Comment: The primary key index has a specific name if you're using mysql or pgsql (`PRIMARY` and `pkey` respectively I think), so you won't be able to drop it by using `entity_id` as the name. Pretty sure the same can be said for sqlite, but it goes about things differently

Answer (score 1):

The function to drop a unique key is [`db_drop_unique_key()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_drop_unique_key/7). You don't need to first check the unique exists, since all the database classes implemented from Drupal first check the unique key exists.

```
// DatabaseSchema_mysql
public function dropUniqueKey($table, $name) {
  if (!$this->indexExists($table, $name)) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  $this->connection->query('ALTER TABLE {' . $table . '} DROP KEY `' . $name . '`');
  return TRUE;
}
```

```
// DatabaseSchema_pqsql
public function dropUniqueKey($table, $name) {
  if (!$this->constraintExists($table, $name . '_key')) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  $this->connection->query('ALTER TABLE {' . $table . '} DROP CONSTRAINT "' . $this->prefixNonTable($table, $name, 'key') . '"');
  return TRUE;
}
```

```
// DatabaseSchema_sqlite
public function dropUniqueKey($table, $name) {
  if (!$this->indexExists($table, $name)) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  $info = $this->getPrefixInfo($table);

  $this->connection->query('DROP INDEX ' . $info['schema'] . '.' . $info['table'] . '_' . $name);
  return TRUE;
}
```

There isn't `db_unique_key_exists()`, nor a `db_primary_key_exists()`, and you should not really need them, since the methods used to drop them first check they exist.

As for using [`db_index_exists()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_index_exists/7), you cannot use it for unique/primary keys because it does not guarantees compatibility with all the database engines. In fact, the database engine for PostGreSQL uses [`DatabaseSchema_pgsql::constraintExists()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21pgsql%21schema.inc/function/DatabaseSchema_pgsql%3A%3AconstraintExists/7) to verify the unique/primary key exists.

```
// DatabaseSchema_pgsql
public function dropPrimaryKey($table) {
  if (!$this->constraintExists($table, 'pkey')) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  $this->connection->query('ALTER TABLE {' . $table . '} DROP CONSTRAINT ' . $this->prefixNonTable($table, 'pkey'));
  return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Good explanation.  Its hard to find this type of information even reading through the api.drupal.org.  In the end, I used  Clive answer.